# Trying to solve the n-parenthesis problem - but failing

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a solution to the 'n-parenthesis problem'

```
def gen_paren_pairs(n): 
   
   
    def gen_pairs(left_count, right_count, build_str, build_list=[]):
        
        print(f'left count is:{left_count}, right count is:{right_count}, build string is:{build_str}')
        
        if left_count == 0 and right_count == 0:
            build_list.append(build_str)
            print(build_list)
            return build_list
            
        if left_count > 0:
            build_str += "("
            gen_pairs(left_count - 1, right_count, build_str, build_list)
            
        
        if left_count < right_count:
            build_str += ")"
            #print(f'left count is:{left_count}, right count is:{right_count}, build string is:{build_str}')
            gen_pairs(left_count, right_count - 1, build_str, build_list)
        
     
    in_str = ""
    gen_pairs(n,n,in_str)
 


gen_paren_pairs(2)
```

It almost works but isn't quite there.
The code is supposed to generate a list of correctly nested brackets whose count matches the input 'n'

Here is the final contents of a list. Note that the last string starts with an unwanted left bracket.

['(())', '(()()']

Please advise.

Comment: What is the "n-parenthesis problem"?

Comment: The program is supposed to generate all legal opening and closing bracket combinations. The number of pairs generated should be the same as an integer passed to the function.

Comment: You should modify "build_str" in the recursive call (without modifying the variable itself) in the same way you did for the counts.

Comment: Hi Michael, that works a treat. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less convoluted approach:

```
memory = {0:[""]}
def gp(n):
    if n not in memory:
        local_mem = []
        for a in range(n):
            part1s = list(gp(a))
            for p2 in gp(n-1-a):
                for p1 in part1s:
                    pat = "("+p1+")"+p2
                    local_mem.append(pat)
        memory[n] = local_mem
    return memory[n]
```

The idea is to take one pair of parentheses, go over all the ways to divide the remaining N-1 pairs between going *inside* that pair and going *after* it, find the set of patterns for each of those sizes, and make all of the combinations.

To eliminate redundant computation, we save the values returned for each input `n`, so if asked for the same `n` again, we can just look it up.

Comment: Recursive is truly amazingly *powerful* in this type of problems.  +1